# Accidently deleted "Setup" entry from Samsung UEFI boot menu. How to get it restored?

Tags: uefi, samsung

I have a Samsung NP900X3C-A07DE laptop. Somehow, I've managed to delete the "Setup" UEFI entry.

Can someone with the same notebook send me output of `efibootmgr -v`, so I can restore mine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved by removing all entries using `efibootmgr` and removing the boot order.

This caused the Samsung NP900X3C-A07DE notebook to restore the system defaults for the EFI boot menu.